# Topologies generated by arbitrary sets.

Tags: general-topology

In my Point Set Topology class, we learned about topologies generated by bases and sub-bases. However, I think I have a notion of a topology generated by arbitrary subsets of the powerset of a given set, but I don't know whether this is a well known topology, or whether the construction is faulty.

Let $S$ be a set, and let $X\subset\mathcal P(S)$. Consider $H$, the set of all topologies on $S$ which contain $X$. Note that $H\neq\varnothing$ thanks to the discrete topology. Consider the reverse inclusion partial ordering ($J \geq K \longleftrightarrow J \subset K$) on $H$, and consider an arbitrary totally ordered subset of $H$, $H'$. Note that $X\subset\bigcap H'$, and that $\bigcap H'$ is a topology on $S$.

We can show this in 3 steps

1. $\varnothing, S\in\bigcap H'$: obvious
2. For all $J\subset\bigcap H'$, $\bigcup J\in\bigcap H'$: $J$ is a subset of all the topologies in $H'$, so $\bigcup J$ is in all of the topologies of $H'$, implying that $\bigcup J\in \bigcap H'$.
3. For $Y,Z\in\bigcap H',\;Y\cap Z\in\bigcap H'$: Again, $Y,Z$ are in every topology in $H'$, which implies that $Y\cap Z$ is as well, so $Y\cap Z\in\bigcap H'$.

Note that $\bigcap H'\geq J$ for all $J\in H'$, and that $\bigcap H'\in H$. Hence, we can apply Zorn's Lemma to show that there exists maximal elements in $H$.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that there exist $K,L\in H$ such that $K\neq L$ and $K,L$ are both maximal. Since $K\not<L$ and $L\not< K$, we have that $K\cap L$ is a topology (this is pretty trivial to show) and that $K\cap L<K,L$, a contradiction. So, we know that we have a single maximal element. This implies that there exists a topology $X'$ such that for every topology $Y$ in $H$, $X'\subset Y$.

So, I propose defining the topology generated by the set $X$ to be $X'$. It seems to be consistent with the notions of topologies generated by bases and sub-bases, but generalizes to arbitrary sets.

Is this construction valid? Is it useful? If the answer to both of these questions is yes, where can I find it in the literature?

Comment: how is this different than a topology generated by a sub-basis?

Comment: @Mirko It shouldn't be. Sub-bases require that their union covers the whole set. This construction doesn't.

Comment: The construction seems valid.  There is a "coarsest possible" topology in which all the subsets of $S$ in $X$ are open.  I can't think of an application of this, but it's late and my coffee supply for today has run out!

Comment: @hardmath it seems general enough to be a common tool in literature. I haven't seen it anywhere though. Any pointers?

Comment: Sometimes we look at a point set map $f:S\to Y$ where $Y$ already has a topology, and we construct the "coarsest possible" topology on $S$ that will make $f$ continuous.  This would be your construction taking $X$ to be the pre-images (under $f^{-1}$) of all the open sets in $Y$.

Comment: @hardmath Interesting! i shall read more. Do you think it's abuse of language to call this construction a topology generated by $X$? My professor is not a fan.

Comment: @hardmath Perhaps if you have time tomorrow, I'd appreciate an answer! Only if you have time, though.

Comment: Sure, I'll do something this weekend.  As far as terminology goes the coarsest or weakest possible topology (containing $X$) is going to sound more familiar to a topologist.  See [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772895/meaning-of-the-weakest-topology-such-that-blank-is-continuous) and this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies).

Comment: The condition that a subbasis covers $S$ isn't really significant. Throwing $S$ into your $X$, you do get a subbasis which generates the same topology as your $X$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That's an interesting statement, that somehow directly contradicts what my professor informed us. Very curious. In his words, "there is no canonical notion of a topology generated by a set whose union does not cover the whole set"

Comment: In my preferred terminology, a subbasis is any collection of subsets of $X$, and the topology you describe is  exactly the topology generated by the subbasis. It's true that some people require a subbasis to cover $X$ - see wikipedia, particularly the "definition" and "alternative definition" sections: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $H$ is a non-empty family of topologies on $S$ then $\cap H$ is a topology on $S.$

If $X\subset \mathcal P(S)$ and $H$ is the set of all topologies $T$ on $S$ such that $T\supset X$ then (i) $ H\ne \emptyset$ because $\mathcal P(S)\in H,$ and (ii) $\cap H$ is the unique $\subset$-minimal member of $H.$

We do not need Zorn's Lemma. For example, to show that $\cap H$ is closed under unions: If $G\subset \cap H$ then for any $T\in H$ we have $G\subset T$ so $\cup G\in T$ (because $T$ is a topology). So $\forall T\in H\,(\cup G\in T),$ so $\cup G\in \cap_{T\in H}(T)=\cap H.$

In set theory the notation $[V]^{<\omega}$ denotes the set of all finite sub-sets of $V.$ If $V\subset \mathcal P(S)$ and $\cup V=S$ then $\{\cap W: W\in [V]^{<\omega}\}$ is a base for a topology $U$ on  $S,$ and $V$ is called a sub-base for $U$. In terms of the $X$ and $H$ of your Q, if $V=X\cup \{S\}$ (to ensure that $\cup V=S$) then $U=\cap H.$

For any $X \subset \mathcal P(S), $ I see no reason not to call $\cap H$ the topology on $S$ generated by $X.$ A standard term is to call $\cap H$ the weakest topology $T$ on $S$ such that $T\supset X.$

Comment: I see, I overcomplicated things. My apologies, but this was helpful! I guess I was confused since my professor said that there was no canonical notion of a topology generated by a subset of the powerset, just of one generated by a basis or sub-basis.

Comment: There is now................

Comment: Haha I guess so.

Comment: See also [that more recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548366).