# Understanding a proposition from Folland's Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Definitions p. 114.
>
> - If $\mathcal T_1$ and $\mathcal T_2$ are topologies on $X$ such that $\mathcal T_1\subset\mathcal T_2,$ we say that $\mathcal T_1$ is **weaker** [...] than $\mathcal T_2.$
> - If $\mathcal E\subset\mathcal P(X)$, there is a unique weakest topology $\mathcal T(\mathcal E)$ on $X$ that contains $\cal E,$ namely the intersection of all topologies on $X$ containing $\cal E.$ It is called the topology **generated** by $\cal E.$

> Proposition 4.4 on page 115: Let $X$ be a nonempty set, $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$, then the topology $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{E})$ generated by $\mathcal{E}$, consist of $\varnothing, X,$ and all unions of finite intersections of members of $\mathcal{E}$.

Is this proposition saying every $U\in \mathcal{T(\mathcal{E})}$ can be expressed as $\bigcup_{i \in \Omega}(\bigcap^{N_i}_{j=1}E_{j,i})$ where $N_i>0$ ? But since $\mathcal{E}$ is not a topology, then we can express open sets as unions of something that may not be open. I'm a bit confused. Can anyone help me understand this?

Thanks

Comment: That proposition seems more like a definition than a proposition. What is the base definition that you are using?

Comment: @FShrike: usually the $\langle$ *structure* $\rangle$ that contains a set is the smallest $\langle$ *structure* $\rangle$ that contains it. The proposition is characterizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cal E$ is not a topology but its elements are open sets of the topology $\mathcal T(\mathcal E)$,  by definition of the latter. Hence finite intersections thereof also are, as well as arbitrary unions of such intersections. What the proposition says is that adding these sets to $\cal E$ is sufficient to get a topology.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. So just to make sure, the topology we get from adding all the union of finite intersections of members of $\mathcal{E}$ to itself, is essential to the topology generated by it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "essentially the topology generated by it" .

Comment: It is necessary to add them to get a topology, and once we have added them, we see that we got indeed a topology, so it is the smallest one containing $\cal E$, i.e. (by definition) it is *exactly* (rather than "essentially") $\mathcal T(\mathcal E)$.

Answer (score 1):

The context is that you have a set $X$ and a subset $\mathcal E\subset X$. There is nothing else, no topology, no open sets, anything. Since the intersection of topologies is a topology and $\mathcal P(X)$ is a topology, there is a smallest topology $\mathcal T(\mathcal E)$ that contains $\mathcal E$. The proposition is characterizing such topology, as the family of sets of the form you wrote.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, I think.