# Weakest topology that makes the interval $(a,b]$ open

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups, weak-topology

I have these two questions:

1) Let $G$ be $\mathbb{R}$ with addition as the group operation and with the weakest topology that makes each interval of the form $(a,b]$ open. Show that $x\rightarrow -x$ is not continuous and hence $G$ is not a topological group.

I know that weakest mean that that topology is the smallest topology, in other words, it is contained by all other topologies that make each interval of the form $(a,b]$ open. What I don't understand is what it means for the topology to make the interval $(a,b]$ open. Is that this topology the collection of arbritrary union of sets of the form $\{(a,b):a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$? This is especially confusing because every element of the topology is called open.

I would like to know then what is the weakest topology that makes each interval of the form $(a,b]$ open.

2) Let $G$ be $\mathbb{R}$ with addition as the group operation and with the topology for which the open sets are either empty or have countable complement (check that this is a topology on $G$). Show that $(x,y)\rightarrow xy$ is continuous if either one of the entries is held fixed but that is not jointly continuous. Hence $G$ is not a topological group.

This question is somewhat similar in nature to the first one. I have the same issue. I don't really know what that topology looks like.

I took a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772895/meaning-of-the-weakest-topology-such-that-blank-is-continuous). That makese sense but I don't know how to extend that to find the topologies for these problems.

I know these questions might be very basic but I am new to topology, so I haven't quite wrapped my head around it yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All possible unions of these intervals (together with the empty set) gives the  weakest topology making these intervals open.

Comment: Ok. So what does saying "that make the interval $(a,b]$ open" imply? Is that equivalent to saying the topology constructed with intervals of the form $(a,b]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection of all subsets of $\Bbb R$ of the form $(a,b]$ is a base for a topology on $\Bbb R$: you can check that it satisfies the [necessary conditions to be a base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Definition_and_basic_properties). That topology consists of the empty set and all sets that are unions of arbitrary families of intervals of the form $(a,b]$. For instance, $\{x\in\Bbb R:x\le 0\}$ is open in this topology, because it is the union of the intervals $(-n,0]$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. $(0,1)$ is also open in this topology: $(0,1)=\bigcup_{x\in(0,1)}(0,x]$. This topology is sometimes called the *upper-limit topology* on $\Bbb R$. Any topology that includes all of the sets of the form $(a,b]$ must contain all unions of such sets, so it must contain the upper-limit topology. This means that the upper-limit topology is the weakest (coarsest) topology making all of those intervals open: any other topology that does so contains all of the open sets in the upper-limit topology and others besides.

One way to show that the map $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto -x$ is not continuous in this topology is to find an open set $U$ in this topology whose inverse image $f^{-1}[U]$ under $f$ is not open in this topology. Try it with $U=(-2,-1]$, which by definition is open in this topology: find $f^{-1}[U]$ and explain why it isn’t open in this topology. HINT: Find a point $p\in f^{-1}[U]$ that has no open nbhd contained in $U$.

The topology in the second question is the *co-countable topology* on $\Bbb R$ and is completely described in the problem statement: it consists of the empty sets and the subsets $U$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $\Bbb R\setminus U$ is countable. (Note that *countable* includes *finite*, so that $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, for instance, is open in the co-countable topology: its complement is the finite (and therefore countable) set $\{0\}$.) We don’t have to build the open sets from some family of basic open sets as we did in the first problem: we already know exactly what the open sets are.

Now you’re asked to consider the map $f:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto xy$, so the first thing to do is to figure out what the product topology on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ is when each factor has the co-countable topology. Remember that the product topology has a base consisting of the products of open sets in the two factors; these are the sets of the form $U\times V$, where $U$ and $V$ are co-countable subsets of $\Bbb R$. That is, there are countable subsets $C$ and $D$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $U=\Bbb R\setminus C$ and $V=\Bbb R\setminus D$. As a non-trivial example, $\Bbb Q$, the set of rationals, is countable, so $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, the set of irrationals, is open in the co-countable topology. So is $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$, the set of non-integers. The Cartesian product of these sets, $(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\times(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z)$, is therefore an open set in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ in the product topology; it consists of all points $\langle x,y\rangle$ in the plane such that $x$ is irrational and $y$ is not an integer.

To finish the problem you must show three things.

1. You must show that $f$ is not continuous. HINT: Let $U=\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$; $U$ is open in the co-countable topology. Figure out what $f^{-1}[U]$ is as a subset of the plane and show that it is not open in the product topology on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$.
2. You must show that if we fix $p\in\Bbb R$ and let $f_p:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:\langle p,y\rangle\mapsto py$, the map $f_p$ **is** continuous with respect to the co-countable topology. To do this, let $U$ be an arbitrary open set in $\Bbb R$, and show that $f_p^{-1}[U]$ is open in the domain.
3. You must show that if we fix $p\in\Bbb R$ and let $f^p:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:\langle x,p\rangle\mapsto xp$, the map $f^p$ is also continuous. This is essentially the same as the second task.

(We say that $f$ is separately continuous, meaning that it is continuous in each variable separately when the other is held fixed, but not jointly continuous, i.e., not continuous as a function of two variables.)

Comment: I've seen you answering other questions. Thank you very much for what you do! I'll read carefully and go through this. If there is something unclear, I'll be back with specific questions. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @Schach21: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @Brian. A pleasure to read.

Comment: 1) if U=(-2,-1], which is open in the topology, then $f^{-1}[U]=[1,2)$, which is not open in the topology, because I can't get sets of the form $[a,b)$ from arbritrary unions or intersection of $(c,d]$ sets. That would still work if $U=[-3,-1)$. I didn't quite the hint about p and a open nbhd of U. 2) 1. If $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$, then $f^{-1}[U]$ would be $1$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$, but $1$ is not in the topology because the complemente is uncountable. 2. $f_p$ is just the identity map scaled by $p$, then if $U$ is open, the preimage of $U$ is open. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: @Schach21: If $U=[-3,-1)$, then $f^{-1}[U]=(1,3]$, which **is** open in the upper-limit topology; that’s why I used a left-open, right-closed interval. The hint points to exactly **why** $f^{-1}[U]$ is not open when $U=(-2,1]$: $1\in f^{-1}[U]$, but the basic open nbhds of $1$ are the sets of the form $(a,1]$ with $a<1$, and none of these is a subset of $f^{-1}[U]$. Thus, $1$ is not in the interior of $U$, and $U$ is not open. For the second question you got off the track very early: when $U=\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$, $f^{-1}[U]$ is the set of all points $\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2$ such ...

Comment: ... that $xy=1$. Thus, it’s the graph of the rectangular hyperbola $xy=1$. Can you show that that graph is not open in the product topology? You’re okay on $f_p$, however.

Comment: Yes, I mistyped. I meant $U=(-3,-1]$. For the second question, why is $f^{-1}[U]$ the set of all points $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $xy=1$? That graph is not open in the product topology, because that graph only contains the points where $D=\{(x,y):xy=1\}$, hence we can find an uncountable set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let's say $\{(x,y):x=0\}$ (or a rectangle), that is not part of $D$, therefore $D^\complement$ is not countable, hence it is not open in the product topology. Hope this is better.

Comment: @Schach21: The map $f$ sends $\langle x,y\rangle$ to $xy$, and the inverse image of $\{1\}$ is the set of all $\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $f(x,y)=1$, so it’s the set of all $\langle x,y\rangle$ such that $xy=1$. Your argument that $D$ isn’t open doesn’t quite work, because there are many open sets in the product topology whose complements are uncountable. One of them, for instance, is the complement of the $x$-axis: it is $\Bbb R\times(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})$ a product of co-countable sets and hence an open set in the product. A better approach is to show that $D$ does not ...

Comment: ... contain any non-empty open set. For this it suffices to show that it does not contain any non-empty basic open set, i.e., any set of the form $U\times V$ where $U$ and $V$ are co-countable subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, the inverse image of $\{1\}$ is the set of all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y)=1$. What I don't see is why we consider the inverse image of $\{1\}$ given that $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$; shouldn't we consider the set of all points where $f(x,y)\neq1$ since $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$? I see why my argument with $D$ is wrong and see why your idea to show that $D$ does not contain any non-empty open set works. I still don't quite know how to show that. My idea would be to fix a $U=x$, then $V=y$ is determined as $y=1/x$, then $V$ is not a co-countable set. But that...-

Comment: ... does not seem rigorous, or even correct.

Comment: @Schach21: My apologies: I was translating some Old Norse at the same time and butchered my last comment. What’s needed is to show that $D$ isn’t **closed** in the product topology or, equivalently, that its complement $W=\Bbb R^2\setminus D$ isn’t open. Consider a basic open set $V=(\Bbb R\setminus A)\times(\Bbb R\setminus B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are countable; this is a subset of $W$ iff its complement contains $D$. Its complement is $\Bbb R^2\setminus V=(A\times\Bbb R)\cup(\Bbb R\times B)$; this is the union of countably many vertical lines and countably many horizontal lines, so it ...

Comment: ... intersects $D$ in only countably many points and therefore certainly doesn’t contain $D$. Thus, $V\nsubseteq W$, and since $V$ was an arbitrary basic open set, $\operatorname{int}W=\varnothing$. In particular, $W$ isn’t open, and therefore $D$ isn’t closed.

Comment: That was beautifully explained. I just have one more question. If $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$, then why is $f^{-1}[U]$ the set of all points $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $xy=1$, or is that what you were apologizing about?

Comment: @Schach21: I was basically apologizing for having temporarily lost track of the thread altogether! Looking back, I see that my original idea was in fact simply to show that $f^{-1}[U]$ isn’t open, which has now been done. Somewhere along the line, though, I got it stuck in my head that I’d suggested something else and confused $f^{-1}[U]$ with its complement. I’m also pretty sure that I misread one of your comments. But I *think* that it’s all straight now.

Comment: Just for verification, if $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$, then $f^{-1}[U]$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $xy\neq 1$? Again, many thanks! With this discussion I've clarified many concepts, more than I did by reading other resources!

Comment: @Schach21: Yes, that’s $f^{-1}[U]$. You’re very welcome; I’m delighted that it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that B ={ (a,b]: a,b in R } is a base for R.
The topology generated by B is the collection
of all unions of half closed intervals in B.
This space is the Sorgenfrey line or the upper limit topology.
1) - is not continuous because  -$^{-1}$((0,1]) = [-1,0) is not open.
2) f(x,y) = xy is not continuous when x is held to -1.
That is because f$^{-1}$(-1,(0,1]) = [-1,0) is not open.

Comment: Wouldn't 2) contradict what I need to show? It says I need to show that it is not jointly continuous but if either element is held fixed, then it is continuous.

Comment: @Schach21.  Indeed it does.  See edit showing why.